# Connecting two list<string>

Tags: list, csv

In order to create csv file I need all needed data in one list which I will represent .AsEnumerable(). I need each element x of both lists to be merged and "," between them. This way csv will read my data as two separate columns (later needed for graph in latex).

I tried .Zip however its syntax is very confusing to me. This is what I've got

```
        foreach (double b in LyapunovFinal)
        {
            LyapunovFinalString.Add(b.ToString());
        }
        foreach (double c in CountTime)
        {
            CountTimeString.Add(c.ToString());
        }
        String[] LyapunovFinalstring = LyapunovFinalString.ToArray();
        String[] CountTimestring = CountTimeString.ToArray();

        Combined = LyapunovFinalstring.Zip(CountTimestring, (first, second) => first + "," + second);

        File.WriteAllLines(path, Combined.AsEnumerable());
```

it returns empty file.

Comment: What programming language are you writing in?

Comment: looks like C# and .NET

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, are the results correct after each line of code?  What ends up in `Combined`?

Comment: It's written in C# and .NET